# How to insert Header and Footer in .vm file

Tags: header, velocity, footer

I have a .vm (Velocity) file which is run to generate a DOC file. I want to have a very simple header and footer in this resultant DOC file. How can I write code in .vm file for this.
I do not want to include header and footer files as external files. I want simple code in the same .vm file.
Please help!!!

Comment: What is VM? Could not find anything about that.

Comment: Without an example and knowing what tools you use to generate the .doc file it won't be possible to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't understand what your need is.  If you want a header and footer in the same file, then just put your header or footer text in there.  If "header" and "footer" are something special in the DOC format, then this isn't a Velocity question at all.  Velocity just writes text out.

Answer (score 1):

Without including a separate file? Just write the HTML. The following code is an extract from a vm file:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footerlinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="first">Something</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```